# convert tiff video into set of images in FIJI / IMAGEJ

Tags: matlab, visualization, imagej

How can I convert tiff video into set of images, should I use plugin？
and export images types should be tif as well, please give me any guide!

Comment: Do you mean in Matlab or ImageJ?

Answer (score 1):

In **ImageJ**, open the video as a stack and save it as an image sequence:

- *File > Open...* and choose your image (or drag and drop)
- *File > Save As > Image Sequence...* and choose *Format: TIFF* and your desired options

See the [ImageJ user guide](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-26.html#sub%3aSaveAs%3EImage-Seq...) for more information.

In [macro](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/macros.html) code:

```
run("Image Sequence... ", "format=TIFF name=[myfilename] start=0 digits=4 save=[/path/to/output/directory]");
```